# Powershell remote sessions and access to network resources

Tags: powershell, remoting, winrm

It seems I cannot access network resources in a remote Powershell session. This is using Powershell v2. Both the local and remote computers are on the same domain.

As an example, if I am on MachineA and connect to MachineB via `Enter-PSSession MachineB`, then from there execute something like `gci \\MachineA\SomeShare`, I get an error: "Cannot find path '\\MachineA\SomeShare' because it does not exist". If I execute the identical command directly from MachineB, I get the results I expect.

I've tried to grant 'read' permissions to 'SomeShare' to 'Everyone' and to the machine account of the remote machine directly. It made no difference.

Is there a configuration change I can make that will allow this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "-authentication CredSSP" to double-hop like that.

[Here's a good link:](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/credssp-for-second-hop-remoting/)

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, as it seems to require reentering credentials, but nevertheless I appreciate the information.

Comment: This link gave me a 403 error. Here is the updated link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/credssp-for-second-hop-remoting/

Comment: thanks...updated the url

Answer (score 1):

for use network acces in remote commande like

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {test-path '\\otherPC\share\'} -Credential (Get-Credential (whoami)) -Authentication Credssp
```

---

To enable client-side SSP for winrm, run the following lines:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer *
```

To enable server-side SSP for winrm:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server
```